# Hiding box with JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm  trying to filter some data (hiding few and keeping some) in my project with this code. I just posted a simple hiding box to take the idea. I'v included jQuery and all files that I need. There is no console error.

```js
if (rad1.checked == true) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".display").css({
      "display": 'none'
    })
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="rad1">ALL student</label>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name='rad1' id='rad1'>
<div class="display" style="background-color:green;width:100px;height:100px"></div>
```

Comment: It's doing exactly what you're telling it to. If the `rad1` checkbox is checked when the page loads, after it loads, hide the box. If you want it to hide/show the box as the checkbox is checked, you'll need to add an event handler for that event. Please do read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an event listener. Otherwise it will only check once when you load the page. It's also good practice to wrap all jQuery in a `$(document).ready()` function to ensure that all document objects will be available.

I started with the `div.display` hidden and then use the `$.toggle()` method to show and hide each time the checkbox is clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#rad1").click(function(event){
        $(".display").toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="rad1">ALL student</label>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name='rad1' id='rad1'>
<div class="display" style="display:none;background-color:green;width:100px;height:100px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should start by checking if the document is ready first, then check if rad1 is checked like so

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    if (rad1.checked === true) {
        $(".display").css({
         "display": 'none'
       });
    }
 }
});
```

If I got your question correctly

Comment: thanks the first answer its doing well

Comment: Cool, I am glad you have it working

Answer (score 0):

`rad1.checked` will only check right as the script is run,you need to bind an event to `rad1` and toggle based on this event. Below is an example of how you can do it.

This way, you also don't need to check if the document is ready yet.

```js
$("#rad1").click(function() {

    $("#rad1").toggle(this.checked);
    if (this.checked) {
      $(".display").css({
        "display": 'none'
      });
    }
    else {
      $(".display").css({
        "display": 'block'
      });
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="rad1">ALL student</label>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name='rad1' id='rad1'>
<div class="display" style="background-color:green;width:100px;height:100px"></div>
```